# change img src based on conditional statement vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am building a radio button, which use a default image (black-radio.png or white-radio.png without checkmark) when the button is not checked, else they use black-radio-checked.png or white-radio-checked.png. But really stuck with this bug. I know there is an option to use computed property, but how should I solve this?

[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/chichichi/pen/vzNPLP?editors=1010)

[image]

```js
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#colorPicker',
    data: {
        color: 'black',
        colors: [
            {
                name: 'black',
                image: 'images/black-radio.png',
                image_checked: 'images/black-radio-checked.png'
            },
            {
                name: 'white',
                image: 'images/white-radio.png',
                image_checked: 'images/white-radio-checked.png'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="colorPicker">    
<div class="display-inline-block">
    <label :for="colorInfo.name" v-for="(colorInfo, index) in colors">
      <input type="radio" name="color" v-model="color" :id="colorInfo.name" class="wireless-headphone-new-input" :value="colorInfo.name"/>
      <img :src="'images/' + colorInfo.name + '-radio.png'">
    </label>
  <div class="confirmation-color capitalize">{{ color }}  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by conditional statement? do you want to show image based on selected checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a radio button is checked, `this.color` value is updated.
So a `v-if` check on `color==colorInfo.name` to show `image_checked` field for the selected radio button and `v-else` to show rest other buttons with  `image` field will do the trick.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#colorPicker',
    data: {
        color: '',
        colors: [
            {
                name: 'black',
                image: 'images/black-radio.png',
                image_checked: 'images/black-radio-checked.png'
            },
            {
                name: 'white',
                image: 'images/white-radio.png',
                image_checked: 'images/white-radio-checked.png'
            }
        ]
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="colorPicker">    
<div class="display-inline-block">
    <label :for="colorInfo.name" v-for="(colorInfo, index) in colors">
      <input type="radio" name="color" v-model="color" :id="colorInfo.name" class="wireless-headphone-new-input" :value="colorInfo.name"/>
      <img v-if="color==colorInfo.name" :src="colorInfo.image_checked">
      <img v-else :src="colorInfo.image"/>
    </label>
  <div class="confirmation-color capitalize">{{ color }}  </div>
  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I add interpolation to img src in vue? and there should be an if else statement or something like that....to check which image they should show (because you have a white-radio.png and white-radio-checked.png)

Comment: what interpolation do you want to add

Comment: You should look at this part-->  <img :src="'images/' + colorInfo.name + '-radio.png'"> . I think it is not possible to add interpolation to an img src attribute like this-->     <img :src="{{curentImgUrl}}/>....but this should also first check if the input is checked, if not then use black-radio.png else black-radio-checked.png.

Comment: it is possible, you can do `<img :src=currentImgUrl  />`

Comment: Ok and how do i check if an input is checked or not....if checked -> black-radio.png else black-radio-checked.png...

Comment: I have updated the code. you can check it by intializing `color:""` initially, which means no radio button is checked currently. On it return black-radio.png or else radio-check.png inside computed function

Comment: Only problem I face now is that all the input buttons have the same color when I click on it. When I use <img :src="currentImgUrl/>...

Comment: can you share that link

Comment: I think this is what you need, you don't need computed for this though. v-if v-else will do

Comment: that is the perfect answer dude ;)

Comment: maybe you could add an extended explanation so anyone could understand your solution in the future.

Comment: Yea need to remove computed and stuff as it is no longer used here.